# Index 1 is out of bounds for axis 3 with size 1

Tags: scikit-learn, deep-learning, keras, theano, spyder

```
output_layer = model.layers[4].output 
output_fn = K.function([model.layers[0].input], [output_layer])
#_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

input_image= X_train[0:1,:,:,:]
print(input_image.shape)

plt.imshow(input_image[0,0,:,:], cmap='gray')
plt.imshow(input_image[0,0,:,:])

output_image = output_fn([input_image])
output_image = np.array([output_image])
print([output_image.shape])

# Rearrnge dimension so we can plot the result as RGB images
output_image = np.rollaxis(np.rollaxis(output_image , 3 , 1) , 3 , 1)
print(output_image.shape)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
for i in range(32):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(6, 6, i+1)
    ax.imshow(output_image[0,:,:,i],interpolation='nearest') 
    ax.imshow(output_image[0,:,:,i],cmap=matplotlib.cm.gray)
    plt.xticks(np.array([]))
    plt.yticks(np.array([]))
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Hi , own convolutional network is working no problem. But For loop is getting this error :

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 3 with size 1
```

Anyone help me ? So thnx.

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems that it comes from either of `ax.imshow()`. Check the dimension ordering of the images, you may be trying to loop over the `channels` dimension of the image which is of size 1. The correct line then would be

```
ax.imshow(output_image[i,:,:,0],interpolation='nearest') 
ax.imshow(output_image[i,:,:,0],cmap=matplotlib.cm.gray)
```

Comment: hi when i change this 2 rows and running now error : `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`

Comment: What is the shape of `output_image` ?

Comment: hi again , output_image.shape this 
`output_image.shape`
`Out[20]: (1, 1, 47040, 1)`

Comment: Well, it's obvious why the error occurs, you're trying to loop over a dimension that has size 1. I can't understand why an image would have that shape. Maybe the output of the print statements would help clear things up. Also, it is unclear what you are trying to achieve using `output_fn`

Comment: Hi please look at below comment, i do little change this shape and code.